# jquery variable in input name selector

Tags: variables, jquery-selectors

I want to use variable in jquery selector to choose checked input and my code is below.
what is wrong here?

```
function MyFunction(MyVariable){
var idAddress = $("input[name='id_address_" +MyVariable+ "']:checked").val();
alert(idAddress);
}
```

Comment: Outside of context, your question makes no sense. Syntactically it is valid.

Comment: If you ask me about details I can explain my problem more specific. Why it is outside of context? Why makes no sense?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net or codepen.io or jsbin.com or another similar site illustrating your problem?

Comment: @tebdilikiyafet It "makes no sense" because your code is correct. The problem is elsewhere so we can't fix it.

Comment: Ok I solved the problem. My variable comes to function as a parameter and I tried to use it directly. It didn't worked. After I assign the parameter to a variable it worked. Is it normal?

Comment: I updated the first code. It is the first version of my code. With this way it doesn't work.

Comment: @tebdilikiyafet there is no reason to assign the parameter to a variable. But you should try to follow the common [javascript style](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml) especially regarding naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically, what you have is correct. It would get any inputs that have the name id_address_ + MyVariable that are checked, and then get the value of the first element, if multiple are returned. If the value of idAddress is null, then you are not getting anything returned from jQuery based on your selection criteria. For that we would need some more code to see the form elements, where MyVariable comes from, etc.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: My variable comes into function as a parameter and I tried to use it directly. After I assign the parameter to a variable it worked. Is it normal? Can't I use function parameter as a variable?